# How to configure correctly to nginx and apache for zendframework2

Tags: php, apache, nginx, zend-framework2

**ENV**

CentOS 6.5 x86_64
PHP 5.6.3
httpd 2.4.10
Nginx 1.6.2
ZendFramework2.3.3

**Target**

Install ZF2 Skeleton Application

**Now**

I configure nginx to pass php files to apache. I configure zf2 skeleton application into a virtual host, either in nginx or apache. I install zendframework2.3.3 manually. I can access website normally by 127.0.0.1:38082(configured by httpd). However, when I access the website by 127.0.0.1:8082(configured by nginx), I got 404 error as below. Anyone can give me some advice? Thanks.

**My Configuration**

*Nginx vhost*

```
server {
    listen       8082;
    server_name  www.eg.m;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  logs/eg.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /data/webapp/www/zf-app/public;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm Default.html Default.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:38082;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}

}
```

*httpd vhost*

```
Listen 38082

<VirtualHost *:38082>
    ServerAdmin w@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/data/webapp/www/zf-app/public"
    ServerName www.eg.m
    ServerAlias eg.m
    ErrorLog "logs/eg.m-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/eg.m-access_log" common

    SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/data/webapp/www/ZendFramework-2.3.3/library"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /data/webapp/www/zf-app/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**I got Error**

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available
```

[image]

**log**

**apache Logs when directly from apache with 127.0.0.1:38082**

*error-log*

```
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.100637 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805499234048] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.100694 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805499234048] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.184903 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805490841344] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.184927 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805490841344] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.186510 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17519:tid 139805499234048] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38935] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.186549 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17519:tid 139805499234048] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38935] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.187952 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805413340928] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.187977 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805413340928] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.189887 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805404948224] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.189901 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805404948224] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.191484 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17519:tid 139805490841344] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38935] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.191502 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17519:tid 139805490841344] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38935] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.242167 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805396555520] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
[Mon Dec 22 19:52:37.242193 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17524:tid 139805396555520] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:38934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1:38082/
```

*access-log*

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5339
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 99548
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1042
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13135
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93107
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 27822
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:19:52:37 +0800] "GET /img/zf2-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 738
```

**apache Logs when access from nginx**

*access-log*

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 404 2345
```

*error-log*

```
[Mon Dec 22 20:29:08.387773 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20897:tid 140375947659008] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:39363] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 22 20:29:08.387818 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20897:tid 140375947659008] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:39363] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

*ngnix access log. no error log*

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 99548 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13135 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1042 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93107 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 27822 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014:20:29:08 +0800] "GET /img/zf2-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 738 "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" "-"
```

Comment: im super tired so just spitballin here but um...you might need the $uri at the end of this:  `proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:38082$uri;` I also didn't read the entire wall of text here so grain of salt but try it anyway

Comment: Thanks @Deryck It does not work.

Comment: Why do you use 2 web servers? If you need Nginx you can dump Apache and use php-fpm

Comment: Well, there should be a way to confingure nginx and apache together when using zf2 @michaelbn. Thanks for your consideration, anyway.

Comment: Hi did you manage to make it work? If so, can you share experience please

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some headers. try adding something like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:38082;
}
```

### -- Update --

I noticed the difference between the log is the http version. I added a rule to force ver 1.1 (check up) - Hope it works

Comment: Still not works. I can sure php files will pass to apache to be deployed. Actually index.php was deployed by apache at the first time. But some part of pages seems not to be found.

Comment: Yes, I can see it fail on routing. Show me the relevant lines from apache log when you access from Nginx and when directly from Apache

Comment: Not works for that. It seems not find `/index.php` at second time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67515/discussion-between-nick-dong-and-michaelbn).